# setting classpath for slf4j for java compiling

Tags: java, classpath, javac, slf4j

I am having a problem setting up the `classpath` for `slf4j` for `compiling java files`.
I tried two ways:
1. provide the `classpath` in `command line`

```
javac -cp /Users/page/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar src/main/java/com/scg/domain/*.java src/main/java/com/scg/util/*.java
```

This gave the following error:

```
src/main/java/com/scg/util/ListFactory.java:8: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
import org.slf4j.Logger;
                ^
src/main/java/com/scg/util/ListFactory.java:9: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...../long error message
```

1. I tried to `export` the `CLASSPATH` to my `env` variable.

`export CLASSPATH=/Users/page/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar`

This did not help either and resulted in same error, when I tried

```
javac src/main/java/com/scg/domain/*.java src/main/java/com/scg/util/*.java
```

I am trying to `compile` all the java files in two `packages`. but I need to have `slf4j` in my classpath`. but somehow I am not able to get it work.`

Thanks

Comment: You need the slf4-api as well, not just a binding-lib. Actually, you need **just** the slf4j-api, the binding-lib is only necessary at runtime.

Comment: @sheltem: sorry can you explain more what you mean here? I got it compiling fine when I used `maven`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This dependency is the api:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

You need the slf4j-api.jar in your classpath for compiling, not the slf4j-log4j12.jar.

It worked in maven because the binding-lib (slf4j-log4j12) has a dependency on the api and thus maven loads that as well, without you explicitly defining it as a dependency.

Comment: maven downloads the depedency if it is not present correct? now that I have used maven already, it should have downloaded that..?

Comment: It should be in your local maven repository, yes. My guess would be `/Users/page/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`